# asp.net an easy way to find the .sln file location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, project, solution

I have to work on a project that I didn't create (Classic situation). Given that where I am working there's no standard where we have to locate the solution, I have no idea where the user before me placed his solution file.

Is there an easy way to find the solution file from a specified project in visual studio ?

**EDIT**

Based on the answer, here's the easy step to get .sln file location :

If you don't see the solution in the "Solution explorer" :

Tools -> Option ->

[image]

And then, right click on the solution :

[image]

**OR**

Select the solution in the Solution explore and then File -> Save as :

You will get the .sln location

Comment: You'll just have to do it the old-fashioned way, `dir *.sln /s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you open the .sln from VS, select the solution (top-most entry) in Solution Explorer, and then `File | Save [...].sln As...`

This should open the `Save As` dialog in the directory of the current solution.

*Edit*

Actually, you can see the path of the solution in the Properties window (property "Path") after you select the solution.

Answer (score 2):

No not really. The project doesn't store a link to the solution as a project can be included in many solution files.

If you're just after opening a single file you can actually just save a new solution. It'll create a new solution file sharing the project name. This might be your best course of action. Alternatively have a search on your file system for some.

Comment: But the project is opened with a .sln file, there's no way to get the location of this solution ? (I open mine with the visual studio recent open project)

Comment: Not quite - visual studio can actually open both projects on a standalone basis, or a solution which can contain many projects. The easiest thing to do is create a new solution.